# RSpec Can't find Ruby Files/Classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using `rspec 2.10` with `Rails 3.2.1` and have problems with classes not being found.

I have put a class called DbTasks under a dir app/util.  Under spec, i've created file `util/db_tasks_spec.rb` which runs afer i included the line:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../app/util/db_tasks')
```

However, `rspec` now isn't able to find my models. I don't want to have to include these manually.  Is there a way to config rspecs paths so everything gets found?

Comment: If you put your file under app/some_folder/some_class.rb and somewhere in your application access SomeClass, then this class will be located automatically. You don't need to include its file manually.

Comment: @jdoe: This is true of rails, but doesn't seem to be true of rspec

Comment: This is true in both cases! You might have put your class in some module and forgot to use it fully qualified name, so Rails couldn't load it.

Comment: Things are set up as i described.  I have a class called Videoset in my models dir and not in any module.  Yet i get the error "uninitialized constant DbTasks::Videoset".  Same with any other of my models.  As mentioned, no problems in Rails, just in rspec.

Comment: Note that your spec tries to find Videoset in DbTasks module. It's hard to say why without seeing your code. Can you push it to github or at least provide some snippets (spec itself would be great)?